# android local broadcast not received from Adapter to service

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-broadcast, expandablelistadapter, localbroadcastmanager

I have a Expandable List Adapter, which i am instantiating in MainActivity

```
ExpAdap adap = new ExpAdap(MainActivity.this);
```

And the constructor of ExpAdap is as below

```
public void ExpAdap(Context cntext){
    mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

I am sending LocalBroadcast, as below

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mInflator.getContext()).sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

In my service, I have registered for a Broadcast receiver to receive . But it's not registering.

The same Broadcast receiver received broadcast, when it is sent from From an adapter, which is set to a ListFragment.

What could be the problem?

Comment: @MD, how it makes difference, because, mInflator is created from a context, on calling getContext, it should return the same. If so, then i think both are same

Comment: @MD Tried, not working !